# Implementing JComponent blinking in Java using threads

Tags: multithreading, graphics, jcomponent

I am trying to implement a program where I want different Components to blink at different speeds. I am using threads. But its not working. 
How can I implement this.

This is the void run function in the class that implements runnable

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if(isVisible()==true)
            {
                setVisible(false);
            }
            else
            {
                setVisible(true);
            }
            repaint();
        }


    }

    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {

    }   
}
```

}
and this is the class (its in a paint component of the main JPanel)where I call the threads-

```
{
    cars[i]=new Car(color, xLocation, yLocation, speed, type, i, widthController, heightController);
    cars[i].setBounds(widthController+(xLocation*50)+10,  heightController+(yLocation*50)+10, 30, 30);
    add(cars[i]);

    threads[i]=new Thread(cars[i]);
    threads[i].start();
}
```

cars is an array of JComponents of which void run is part of.

Thanks

Comment: Umm. Its not blinking. But the void run() is definitely getting executed though cause when I put a System.out.println in it, its gets printed infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

With Swing, all operations that affect visible components should be run on the AWT-EventQueue. This is a dedicated thread for Input/Output operations as well as drawing and component operations. My recommendation is to use a swing timer for your run operation. The repaint call you made will call the paintCompnent method on the AWT-EventQueue. However you're changing the state of visibility on a seperate thread. This means that by the time the repaint call is made, it's possible the state has already changed to the previous value.

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.Timer;
 //Rest of code above...
     //This will execute the timer every 500 milliseconds
     Timer aTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pE) {
         aComponent.setVisible(!aComponent.isVisible());

     }
    });
    aTimer.start();
```

Another option is that on each thread add this call:
//This should be added inside of your thread

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    aComponent.setVisible(!aComponent.isVisible());
    }
});
```

Here's the answer I was alluding to in my comments:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                setVisible(!isVisible());
            }

        }
    });


    }

    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Umm, thanks but I am supposed to use threads for this. Its like, you start up a thread for each component and they blink at different speeds all over the JPanel.

Comment: Then you're left with two options: 1) Block the EDT every time you change state (state being visibility), if you do that off the thread or 2) Have the thread submit a runnable type to the EDT by using SwingUtilties.invokeLater inside of your thread method. The problem with multi threaded is that there's nothing built in to stop the threads from changing state from each other. This is caused a race condition, as it the outcome of two threads modifying/accessing the same state at the same state cannot be determined.

Comment: I went ahead and added my second suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I tried the second suggestion. thank you. but whenever i use set visible, the program goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: How did it get in an infinite loop? What did you put in the invokeLater? Did you override the setVisible method?

Comment: No, I did not. It still getting into one though!

Comment: Could you post the stack trace and the source?

Comment: Wait, is the second part of your code above in the paintComponent method? If so, that's why it's in an infinite loop. That code should be moved outside of the paintComponent. In fact you shouldn't override the paintComponent as that's the method that does the actual drawing. The add method should be called once.